# How can I compress repetitive characters to a single character using RE in Python?

Tags: python, regex, compression, repeat

I want to be able to replace any consecutive occurrences of punctuation characters in a string with a single occurrence. 
For example:

- "I went to the park...." => "I went
  to the park."
- "Are you serious??!!???!" => "Are you
  serious?!?!"

The first thing that came to mind was to:

```
for char in string.punctuation:
  text = re.sub( "\\" + char + "+",  char,  text )
```

However, since this is going to run in a repetitive process, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this in a single RE, in order to make it run faster. What do you think?

Comment: thanks guys both were great fast answers. I could only accept one though so I chose the one who corrected my way of escaping the punctuation string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
text = re.sub(r"([" + re.escape(string.punctuation) + r"])\1+", r"\1", text)
```

This uses `re.escape()` to ensure that the punctuation characters are properly escaped as necessary. The `\1` backreferences refer to the part within the parentheses `()`, which is the *first* punctuation character matched. So this replaces instances of two or more repeated punctuation characters with the same single character.

Answer (score 3):

`re.sub(r'([!?.])\1+', r'\1', text)`